# Implementar métodos em cascata (cascade) em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

No livro **JavaScript: The Good Parts**, Douglas Crockford explica o conceito de método em cascata, do inglês cascade. Segundo o autor estes métodos são caracterizados por alterarem o estado do objeto sem retornar nada. Os métodos aninhados retornam this. Segue o exemplo retirado do livro de Crockford:

```
getElement('myBoxDiv').
move(350, 150).
width(100).
height(100).
color('red').
border('10px outset').
padding('4px').
appendText("Please stand by").
on('mousedown', function (m) {
this.startDrag(m, this.getNinth(m));
}).
on('mousemove', 'drag').
on('mouseup', 'stopDrag').
later(2000, function ( ) {
this.
color('yellow').
setHTML("What hath God wraught?").
slide(400, 40, 200, 200);
}).
tip('This box is resizeable');
```

**Como implementar este padrão com JavaScript? Existe alguma boa prática para esta implementação?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As bibliotecas de JavaScript usam frequentemente este conceito, o MooTools é o caso mais abrangente creio eu.

Para implementar esta ideia em código seu todos os métodos que queira encadear têm de retornar um novo Tipo/Type que contenha os métodos que chama a seguir.

## Um exemplo com JavaScript nativo,

sem ter de fazer nada de novo:

```
var string = 'olá mundo!';
var letras = string.split('').filter(function(letra){ return /[a-z]/i.test(letra); }).join('');
```

**Neste caso o que se passa?**

Temos uma string como ponto de partida. Aplicando o método `.split('')` deixamos de ter uma string e passamos a ter uma array. Ora então mudámos de *String Type* para *Object/Array Type*. O produto deste primeiro método foi:

```
["o", "l", "á", " ", "m", "u", "n", "d", "o", "!"]
```

Esta array vai ser o material/input que o próximo método vai usar. O proximo método `.filter()` vai retirar dessa array valores da array que não sejam letras "simples". O pruduto será uma array ainda um *Tipo Array* que irá ser passado ao método de arrays `.join()` que irá devolver uma *String*.

Neste exemplo usamos código em cascata, nativo. (Demo online: http://jsfiddle.net/8ubcL83q/)

Para aplicar o mesmo conceito a código feito por sí tem de ter em conta que todos os métodos que chamar têm de produzir/retornar algo que possa ser usado no próximo método encadeado para a cascata funcionar.

A maneira de fazer isso é assegurar que no final do método existe um `return`. A seguir a esse `return` vem o que quer retornar:

```
return variavelComProdutoParaOProximoMetodoConsumir;
```

Analizando o seu código vejo que ele começa com um *getter* `getElement('myBoxDiv')` que devolve um objeto/elemento do DOM. A partir daí, analizando o que está a ser feito, deduzo que todos esses métodos têm no seu final `return this;` e desse modo todos esses métodos estão a ser aplicados ao mesmo elemento com que a cadeia/cascata começou.

### Um exemplo de um código usando a biblioteca do MooTools:

(demo online **[aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/hdfv33jo/1)**)

```
document.id('foo').getParent('div').setStyle('border', '2px solid #ccf').addEvent('click', function(){
   alert(this.get('text')); 
});
```

Neste caso `document.id('foo')` é uma função que o MooTools adicionou ao objeto  `document`, que passa como argumento uma *string*, "foo". Esta função/método vai buscar o elemento do DOM com a ID `foo` e retorna um *objeto*/ elemento do DOM.

De seguida o `.getParent('div')` vai subir no DOM e retornar o primeiro `div` que encontrar. Esse novo *objeto*/ elemento do DOM será o produto usado no próximo método. Assim `.setStyle('border', '2px solid #ccf')` vai aplicar uma linha na borda do elemento.

Este método para aplicar CSS retorna o próprio elemento que modificou. À semelhança do seu exemplo, o `setStyle()` faz o que lhe é pedido e retorna o elemento do DOM.

Assim é possivel o próximo método ser aplicado a esse elemento.

*Note que o MooTools acresenta novos métodos ao prototype de Elementos, daí que é muito útil retornar o objeto `this` no final de cada método.*

### Para fazer o seu próprio código em cascata:

Aqui fica um exemplo, com a mesma funcionalidade do que o meu exemplo em MooTools faz:

```js
var metodos = {
    objeto: null,
    getID: function (seletor) {
        var el = document.getElementById(seletor);
        this.objeto = el;
        return this;
    },
    getParent: function (tag) {
        tag = tag.toUpperCase();
        var elm = this.objeto, x = 0;
        while (elm.nodeName != tag && elm.nodeName != 'body') {
            elm = elm.parentNode;
        }
        this.objeto = elm;
        return this;
    },
    setStyle: function (propriedade, valor) {
        this.objeto.style[propriedade] = valor;
        return this;
    },
    addEvent: function (tipo) {
        this.objeto.addEventListener(tipo, function () {
            alert('Estou a funcionar!');
        });
        return this;
    }
}
metodos.getID('foo').getParent('div').setStyle('border', '2px solid #ccf').addEvent('click');
```

```css
div {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div><span>Span 1</span>

    </div>
    <div><span id="foo">Span 2 (pode clicar aqui...)</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

A função deve retornar `this`. Aqui está um exemplo:

```js
function criarPessoa(nome) {
    return {
        nome: nome,
        idade: 25,
        alterarNome: function(nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
            return this;
        },
        alterarIdade: function(idade) {
            this.idade = idade;
            return this;
        }
    };
}

var pessoa = criarPessoa("Maria").alterarIdade(30).alterarNome("Paulo");
alert("Nome: " + pessoa.nome + "; Idade: " + pessoa.idade);
```

Comment: Simples e preciso.